# Read line for first top 10 lines and display word in each line of 10 lines using PHP

Tags: php, file

I have the PHP code as below:

```
<?php
    $path = "files/stats_pmta.affinitead.net.2012-12-12.txt";
    $num = 10;
    $fh = @fopen($path, 'r');
    if ($fh){
    for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
    $newfile = fgets($fh,1024);     
    $t = explode(";", $newfile);
    echo $t;
    echo "<br>";
    }


    } else {
        echo 1;
    }
```

?>

I want to read all data in file `stats_pmta.affinitead.net.2012-12-12.txt` that read only first 10 lines of the file below:

```
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;gmail.com;123577;7780;6.29
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;wanadoo.fr;123562;9227;7.46
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;yahoo.fr;104819;1685;1.60
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;orange.fr;87132;7341;8.42
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;laposte.net;79597;1040;1.30
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;hotmail.fr;77601;14107;18.17
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;neuf.fr;67392;1793;2.66
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;hotmail.com;55300;10494;18.97
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;free.fr;43422;1706;3.92
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;sfr.fr;39063;251;.64
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;aol.com;32061;9859;30.75
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;club-internet.fr;22424;233;1.03
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;yahoo.com;18646;1365;7.32
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;voila.fr;18513;3650
```

After I read first top 10 lines I want to display the word in each line like:

```
2012-12-12-0551;affinitead.net;1221588;106346;8.70;gmail.com;123577;7780;6.29
```

I want to display `gmail.com` `123577` `7780` `6.29`

But PHP code above I just got the output `array`.I don't know how to fix this.Anyone help me please , Thanks.

Comment: Best option is to split... First, split your text by new line, `\n` and then by `;` semi-colon. The newline will get you your rows and semi-colon will return an array of values in which you can use `$row[5]` to access `gmail.com` `$row[6]` to access `123577` and so on.

Comment: Also, you might be better off using `file_get_contents` if you are just wanting to read the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way you could do it by using the PHP-function explode.

```
$textFile = file_get_contents("test.txt");

                $lineFromText = explode("\n", $textFile);

                $row = 0;
                foreach($lineFromText as $line)
                {
                        if($row <= 10)
                        {
                        $words = explode(";",$line);
                        echo $words[5] . ' ' . $words[6] . ' ' . $words[7] . ' ' . $words[8];
                        $row++;
                        }   
                }
```

Edited the code so that you can replace your own, you might want to check if the file is empty e t c before trying to do anyting thou.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.For this line 11 `echo 'Wanted words:" . $words[5] . ' ' . $words[6] . ' ' . $words[7] . ' ' . $words[8];` it displays but I got the error that `Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\wamp\www\chat\chat.php on line 11`.

Comment: I just copied your text into a variable called $textFile and ran my code and it worked out and showed Wanted words:gmail.com 123577 7780 6.29 Wanted words:wanadoo.fr 123562 9227 7.46 Wanted words:yahoo.fr etc... You might have to remove your initial exploding and just run the code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$path = 'path/to/file'
$fp = fopen($path, 'r');
$count = 0;
while($columns = fgetcsv($fp, 256, ';', '"')
{
    if(++$count > 10)
        break;

    echo implode("\t", $colums);
}
```

If you don't know, how implode works, look here: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php